# How to extract RPM files to specific package from Java

Tags: java, rpm

I want to extract a rpm file to target directory from Java code. I'm aware of the following approaches:

- Run `rpm2cpio mypackage.rpm | (cd /target/dir; cpio -idmv)` as command line. This is not really Java and I worry the portability by hardcoding this command.
- Use `CpioArchiveInputStream`. I hit `java.io.IOException: Unknown magic` when trying to read the rpm file. My guess is that this library is too old to adapt to new archive/compression types.

Is there a better approach that I'm not aware of? Ideally something that works like a `TarArchiveInputStream` would be perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the middle ground that I found working:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process proc = rt.exec(String.format("rpm2cpio %s", packagePath));
try (CpioArchiveInputStream cpioStream = new CpioArchiveInputStream(proc.getInputStream())) {
    System.out.println(cpioStream.getNextCPIOEntry().getName());
}
```

Not perfect, but makes it easier so that we only rely on a new process to read file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. An alternative using pure java is as follows:

- Use [com.jguild.jrpm.io.RPMFile.readFromStream](https://sourceforge.net/p/jrpm/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/main/java/com/jguild/jrpm/io/RPMFile.java#l284) to read the RPM file opened as a stream. This will:

  - Read the RPM headers
  - Position the stream to the beginning of the archive data
- Wrap the stream with an [org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.cpio.CpioArchiveInputStream](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/apidocs/org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/cpio/CpioArchiveInputStream.html) starting at the current position
- Use [getNextCPIOEntry](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/apidocs/org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/cpio/CpioArchiveInputStream.html#getNextCPIOEntry) to read the CPIO archive, entry by entry

  - Use the properties of the result, a [CpioArchiveEntry](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/apidocs/org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/cpio/CpioArchiveEntry.html), to create a corresponding local file system entry
  - If a directory, it has no data; just create it
  - If a symbolic link, the data is the target of the link; create it on the local file system
  - If a regular file, the data is contents of the file; write it to the local file until a (simulated) end of file is reached
  - Other types (pipe, device node, ...) can be handled as appropriate
  - Update local entry's permissions, ownership, group, etc., as appropriate
- Repeat until no more archive entries remain